# Jquery: filter data from HTML attribute and show/hide result

Tags: jquery

I have an inputbox that allows the user to search for a contact based on the contact number or contact name and I want the search result display only if it is matched with either name or number. The contact number is storing in the data attribute `data-contact-id` and the name is displayed inside `label` tag.

But I am stuck here.  Below are the simple structure of data.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gcta5jb/)

```js
$('#input_search').on("keyup", function() {
  var user_input = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  
  // Stuck here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search for contact" id="input_search">
</div>
<div class="forward-body">
  <div class="model" data-contact-id="44">
    <label class="label-name">cccc1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="model" data-contact-id="555888">
    <label class="label-name">Jason</label>
  </div>

  <div class="model" data-contact-id="alibaba
">
    <label class="label-name">AliBABA
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="model" data-contact-id="221222">
    <label class="label-name">Wababa wakanda</label>
  </div>

  <div class="model" data-contact-id="123123
">
    <label class="label-name">Alibaba Wababa
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="model" data-contact-id="9">
    <label class="label-name">testing_9</label>
  </div>

  <div class="model" data-contact-id="6">
    <label class="label-name">data_number_6</label>
  </div>

  <div class="model" data-contact-id="5">
    <label class="label-name">data_number5</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all `.model` divs using `.each` then check if the value enter by user matches either attribute or label depending on this `show` that model div else `hide`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.search-container input#input_ssearch').on("keyup", function() {
  var number = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (number != "") {
    $(".model").hide(); //hide all model divs
    //loop through model divs
    $(".model-container .model").each(function() {
      //check if value input matches attr or label
      if (($(this).attr('data-contact-id') == number) || ($(this).find('label.forward-message-contactname').text().toLowerCase().trim() == number)) {
        $(this).show() //show that
      }

    })
  } else {
    $(".model").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="model-container">
  <div class="search-container">
    <i class="fa fa-search bigger-130"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for contacts" id="input_ssearch">
  </div>
  <div class="forward-body">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 model" data-contact-id="44">
      <input class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" type="checkbox" id="forward-message-checkbox" name="forward message">
      <label class="col-md-11 col-xs-11 forward-message-contactname">cccc1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 model" data-contact-id="Sad">
      <input class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" type="checkbox" id="forward-message-checkbox" name="forward message">
      <label class="col-md-11 col-xs-11 forward-message-contactname">Sad</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 model" data-contact-id="AliBABA
">
      <input class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" type="checkbox" id="forward-message-checkbox" name="forward message">
      <label class="col-md-11 col-xs-11 forward-message-contactname">AliBABA
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 model" data-contact-id="9">
      <input class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" type="checkbox" id="forward-message-checkbox" name="forward message">
      <label class="col-md-11 col-xs-11 forward-message-contactname">9</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 model" data-contact-id="6">
      <input class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" type="checkbox" id="forward-message-checkbox" name="forward message">
      <label class="col-md-11 col-xs-11 forward-message-contactname">6</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 model" data-contact-id="5">
      <input class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" type="checkbox" id="forward-message-checkbox" name="forward message">
      <label class="col-md-11 col-xs-11 forward-message-contactname">5</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 model" data-contact-id="44">
      <input class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" type="checkbox" id="forward-message-checkbox" name="forward message">
      <label class="col-md-11 col-xs-11 forward-message-contactname">cccc1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 model" data-contact-id="Sad">
      <input class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" type="checkbox" id="forward-message-checkbox" name="forward message">
      <label class="col-md-11 col-xs-11 forward-message-contactname">Sad</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 model" data-contact-id="AliBABA
">
      <input class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" type="checkbox" id="forward-message-checkbox" name="forward message">
      <label class="col-md-11 col-xs-11 forward-message-contactname">AliBABA
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 model" data-contact-id="9">
      <input class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" type="checkbox" id="forward-message-checkbox" name="forward message">
      <label class="col-md-11 col-xs-11 forward-message-contactname">9</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 model" data-contact-id="6">
      <input class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" type="checkbox" id="forward-message-checkbox" name="forward message">
      <label class="col-md-11 col-xs-11 forward-message-contactname">6</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 model" data-contact-id="5">
      <input class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" type="checkbox" id="forward-message-checkbox" name="forward message">
      <label class="col-md-11 col-xs-11 forward-message-contactname">5</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your code doesn't work for the searching. As for the data sample here, if you input 'c' in the searchbox and the whole div is hide.

Comment: so you need to show div when one letter is typed as well ?

Comment: yes... Oh yeah.. I sorted it out with little modification from your code.

Comment: just modify your code from the inner `if` statement with `.indexOf(number) > -1`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I will still mark your answer ;)